# Group rows in multiple columns and count

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table with these data :

```
SELECT typeId, status FROM geo WHERE userId = 1 LIMIT 5;
+--------+--------+
| typeId | status |
+--------+--------+
|      2 | 2      |
|      2 | 5      |
|      8 | 2      |
|      3 | 3      |
|      2 | 5      |
+--------+--------+
```

And I'd like to count the number of different status per typeID. Here the expected result:

```
status 2 = active
status 3 = disabled
status 5 = archived

+--------+--------+----------+----------+
| typeId | active | disabled | archived |
+--------+--------+----------+----------+
|      2 | 1      | 0        | 2        |
|      8 | 1      | 0        | 0        |
|      3 | 0      | 1        | 0        |
+--------+--------+----------+----------+

0 can be is NULL, not a problem
```

I tried with a query like that : "SELECT typeId, CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN status END AS active, CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN status END AS disabled, CASE WHEN status = 5 THEN status END AS archived FROM `geo` WHERE `userId` = 1 group by typeId" but of course it's not the expected result.. I got the status, not the count and I don't know how to count them.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to apply an aggregate function `count(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN status END)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need aggreaation functions:

```
SELECT typeId, SUM( status = 2 ) AS active, SUM( status = 3 ) AS disabled, SUM( status = 5 ) AS archived
FROM geo
WHERE userId = 1 
GROUP BY typeId;
```

Note that this uses a convenient MySQL shortcut that sums boolean values "as if" they were integers, with `1` for true and `0` for false.

Comment: Thank you, the solution is simpler than I thought it would be!

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this way (for T-SQL):

```
SELECT typeId,
       SUM(CASE status WHEN '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'active',
       SUM(CASE status WHEN '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'disabled',
       SUM(CASE status WHEN '5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'archived'
FROM geo
WHERE userId = 1
GROUP BY typeID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the case expression with count function:

```
SELECT typeId,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN '2' THEN 1 END) AS 'active',
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN '3' THEN 1  END) AS 'disabled',
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN '5' THEN 1  END) AS 'archived'
FROM Table1
GROUP BY typeID;
```